What are the `rpmlib(foo)` and `mvn(foo)` dependencies that are listed as RPM package "requirement tags"?
Suppose I have installed the package ongres-scram on Fedora 40.
Then
$ rpm --query --requires ongres-scram

gives me a list of "dependency tags" that are required to have this package installed:
javapackages-filesystem
mvn(com.ongres.stringprep:saslprep)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1
rpmlib(RichDependencies) <= 4.12.0-1

Conversely
$ rpm --query --provides ongres-scram

gives me "dependency tags" that are provided by the installation:
mvn(com.ongres.scram:common) = 2.1
mvn(com.ongres.scram:common:pom:) = 2.1
ongres-scram = 2.1-13.fc40

The dependency tag javapackages-filesystem is resolved by a corresponding package:
$ rpm --query --whatprovides javapackages-filesystem
javapackages-filesystem-6.2.0-9.fc40.noarch

The dependency tag mvn(foo) certainly has to do with a build process based on maven and can be resolved:
$ rpm --query --whatprovides "mvn(com.ongres.stringprep:saslprep)"
ongres-stringprep-1.1-12.fc40.noarch
$ dnf provides "mvn(com.ongres.stringprep:saslprep)"
...
ongres-stringprep-1.1-12.fc40.noarch : RFC 3454 Preparation of Internationalized Strings in pure Java
...

But the dependency tag rpmlib(foo) is not resolved:
$ rpm --query --whatprovides "rpmlib(FileDigests)"
no package provides rpmlib(FileDigests)
$ dnf provides "rpmlib(FileDigests)"
Error: No matches found....

It may be that the tag stands for a requirement on the system to build the RPM package. But what provides it?
Moreover it seems
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1

indicates a requirement for quite an old version as the current rpm is 4.19.1.1?

rpmlib dependencies are capability flags stored in RPM headers, indicating features which rpm itself must support in order to process the RPM. The version relationships read back to front: the ongres-scram RPM thus needs a version of rpm which supports zstd-compressed payloads, and this feature is only available in rpm 5.4.18 or later.
You can see which capabilities your rpm command supports by running
rpm --showrc | grep rpmlib

If you examine requirements with yum or dnf you’ll see that these rpmlib dependencies aren’t visible: they’re tied to specific RPM files, not general properties of the package itself. That is to say, rebuilding the package with different settings shouldn’t affect the “real” dependencies (on libraries etc.), but it might affect required capabilities (for example if the RPM is compressed using a different algorithm).
mvn dependencies are dependencies on Maven packages, as you discovered.

Excellent, thank you. I just asked ChatGPT this question and it didn't know that the <= needs to be read backwards, so it tried to explain that requiring a version that is lower than some other given version is quite unusual indeed in a whole paragraph.  That is so student-like...
